# How to debug iOS App when opened from TodayExtension with openUrl?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have mini-app with Today Extension and I created a custom URL Scheme.
Then after clicking a UIButton in the extension, I've called the open function like

```
extensionContext?.open(URL(string: "todayextensionexample://inform")!, completionHandler: nil)
```

The application has started successfully but I cannot debug it.

I try 3 different approaches.

First of all for open debugging `Edit Scheme -> Info -> Wait for executable to be launched` for executable to be launched in Application scheme but the application waits and there's no launch so there's no debug.

My ( open url: URL ) function is like below:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.urlOpenedNotification, object: nil, userInfo: nil)

    return true

}
```

in viewDidLoad method of the ViewController;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationHandler(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.urlOpenedNotification, object: nil)

    }
```

This was my second approach.

The 3. approach is that using parsing the URL parameters and logging it like below:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {


let sendingAppID = options[.sourceApplication];
print("source application = \(sendingAppID ?? "Unknown") ")

guard let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
    let path = components.path,
    let params = components.queryItems else {
        print("Invalid URL or album path missing")
        return false
}



print("components > ", components)
print("path > ", path)
print("params >", params)

var param: [String: Any] = ["components": components, "path": path, "params": params];

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.urlOpenedNotification,
                                object: nil,
                                userInfo: param)


return true
}
```

In 3. approach, I tried that Notification & printing some variables.

Before my questions; I change some of `print()`'s to `NSLog()` but in the `Device -> Show Logs` there's nothing works.

Application has opened with openUrl but I cannot debug it because if I start the `TodayExtension` target the Application not debugging and otherside if I start Application target, when I click the `TodayExtension` button then open the app again when it background

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL ...)
```

function is not working. I've seen the debugs of the real device but there's nothing to see.

Is there any way to after clicking the button on Today Extension then Xcode has started the main application target and I will able to see the all of the logs?

How can I debug it and see check if its successfully working?

Comment: Go to Edit Scheme and select option - "Wait for executable to be launched". then place breakpoint in OpenURL Method. Run the application your breakpoint will get called now when open a url from Today's extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Override an initializer in your App Delegate, and add there sleep call.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        sleep(10000)
    }
    ...
}
```

2) Install this app on your device or simulator.

3) Put a breakpoint in your code.

4) From the extension, trigger the deeplink.

5) While app is opened and in sleep, connect your Xcode debugger to your app via Xcode app menu (`Debug`->`Attach To Process`->`< your app name >`). This will instantly wake up your app and it will fall into the breakpoint immediately.

Comment: Hey Eugene, I achieved it thanks for it, is there any way to see my print & logs when I try it in Xcode console? I try to see that in device logs & Console app but I cannot see the logs for it.

Comment: In order to log to the device console, you can use CocoaLumberjack library (https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/README.md), `DDOSLogger` class, for convenience, or directly one of the `<os/log.h>` functions, e.g. `os_log_debug`.